# My postman Json is accepting everything even with the fields being restricted

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, postman

I made a spring boot setup with java, and I made some restrictions for the Json to not accept some kind of values, but when I input the values on my Json, my postman is accepting every value that I input

User.java class

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Name field cannot be blank.")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "Name must be between 2 and 50 characters.")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "DDD field cannot be blank.")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 2, message = "DDD must have 2 characters.")
    private String ddd;

    @NotBlank(message = "Phone Number field cannot be blank.")
    @Size(min = 8, max = 9, message = "Phone number must have between 8 and 9 digits.")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email field cannot be blank.")
    @Email(message = "Invalid email format.")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password field cannot be blank.")
    @Size(min = 8, max = 12, message = "Password must be between 8 and 12 characters")
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String ddd, String phoneNumber, String email, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ddd = ddd;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // Standard getters and setters
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getDdd() {
        return ddd;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, user.id) &&
                Objects.equals(email, user.email);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, email);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", ddd='" + ddd + '\'' +
                ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
UserController.java

package com.example.demo.controller;
import com.example.demo.model.User;
import com.example.demo.service.UserService;
import com.example.demo.service.MailService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final MailService mailService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService, MailService mailService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.mailService = mailService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userService.getUserById(id);
        return userOptional
                .map(user -> new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK))
                .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        if (userService.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT); // Email already exists
        }
        User newUser = userService.saveOrUpdateUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody User user) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userService.getUserById(id);
        if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
            // Ensure the ID from the path matches the ID of the user being updated
            user.setId(id);
            User updatedUser = userService.saveOrUpdateUser(user);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @PostMapping("/sendVerificationEmail")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendVerificationEmail(@RequestParam String email) {
        // Generate a verification code or content if needed
        String verificationContent = "Your verification content here";

        // Use your MailService to send the email
        mailService.sendVerificationEmail(email, "Verification Email", verificationContent);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Email sent successfully.");
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        if (userService.getUserById(id).isPresent()) {
            userService.deleteUser(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

[Json Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWdq0.png) I made an example with this picture for a better understanding
Thanks for the help

I tried to put new dependecies on gradle like

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:7.0.2.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.5.6.Final'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
}
```

but it's not working

Comment: I believe you need to annotate your controller fields with @Validated for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

what happens is that in the entity or model that you are using as a response in your RestController that is "api/users", the User class or object does not have an attribute with a constraint of the default json converter of spring that is com.fasterxml.jackson.

Lo que debes es marcar con la anotación @JsonIgnore en la propiedad:

```
public class User(){
  
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@JsonIngnore
@NotBlank(message = "Name field cannot be blank.")
@Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "Name must be between 2 and 50 characters.")
private String name;}
```

Comment: but my issue is for example the DDD field should allow just 2 numbers but is allowing more than that. this is also happening with the other fields is not respecting the restrictions that i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you're not intercepting RequestBody validations.
The comptroller should look something like this to get the errors on the application if you have them:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
         Map<String, String> errores = new HashMap<>();
    result.getFieldErrors().forEach(err -> {
        errores.put(err.getField(), String.format("El campo %s %s", err.getField(), err.getDefaultMessage()));
    });
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errores);

    if (userService.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT); // Email already exists
    }
    User newUser = userService.saveOrUpdateUser(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(newUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Spring already has an interface that captures these validations and that is the BindingResult.